# Why do some fields have no weeds?

Tags: nature-and-wildlife, identify-this

When driving sometimes I'll see fields that don't appear to have any weeds and where all the grass is short. It'll look like a field that's been mowed except I can't really see any reason to mow these fields. Maybe grazing animals are keeping the grass down but if that were the case it seems like you'd see grazing animals but I usually don't..

Here's a sample pic:

[image]

Comment: Could it be grass that's been harvested for hay?

Comment: not even remotely a travel question

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about agriculture.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its offtopic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does look like animals (including wild animals) are grazing on this field. It's also possible that some animals were brought there especially to maintain the landscape (“conservation grazing”). In that case, you wouldn't expect to see animals most of the time and, since feeding is not the main purpose of the land, it does not exhibit some features typical of more intensive pasture (limited forest cover, etc.)

In any case, even regular pasture is rarely densely populated. You need to allow time for the vegetation to recover, enough space for the animals to move around. Some animals will also be somewhere else (e.g. for milking, calving, shearing, slaughtering, etc.) and in some seasons you won't see many animals even in regions with open landscape and large herds.

Finally, some areas (entire regions e.g. in Ireland or more limited areas elsewhere) are too wet for grass and ultimately forest cover to develop. From a distance, they can look like a mowed lawn.

Comment: And then there's the little fact that the image is taken from such a distance that any weeds growing in it would be indistinguishable from grass in what becomes a slightly mottled green plane... Or maybe it's a golf course, which would appear plausible seeing that some parts seem to be mown to a lower height of vegetation than others, and some not at all.